# Removing redirect away from User page on Rails Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

So I've adapted the Rails tutorial a little, and am trying to use the Micropost feature as a listing of posts only.

The problem is that when the micropost is deleted, the focus goes back to the root URL and I am looking to not redirect. My trial and error didn't work.

Essentially, what am I looking for. After the deletion of the post, I'd like the focus to remain on the user/1 page, which is the display listing of microposts. I tried simply removing the line of code for the redirect, but that was not the answer.

Here's the micropost controller:

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_filter :correct_user, only: :destroy

  def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(params[:micropost] )
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      @feed_items = [ ]
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @micropost.destroy
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  def correct_user
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to root_url if @micropost.nil?
  end

end
```

Comment: Ok,I got it. I used the @current_user path instead of the root_url path and that did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comment, I found the answer by trial and error. I changed the redirect_to. It then reads: 
redirect_to @current_user
which did the trick.